# I've lost my CV, how do I rebuild it?

Tags: resume, united-kingdom

Due to some unlucky happen-stance, losing boxes during a house move & hard disk crashes, I find myself without a copy of my current CV.  I'm 50 and have moved jobs a number of times (including some temping & contact work), been made redundant a couple of times and had short periods of unemployment.  I've got a general framework of where I've worked with rough dates, but I need to tie it all down better than that, especially the periods where I wasn't working.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I could try and get more information?  I've asked any ex-colleagues that I'm still in contact with, but obviously they don't have precise details of my employment, just their own.

Edit: Thanks all for the comments & suggestions, trying to get details through my NI contributions was probably the most useful.  I was sorting through my loft at the weekend and I stumbled upon an old CD box that I'd forgotten I'd got which, along with installers for v.old OSs and various other stuff, contained a disk with a backup file of a computer from 2002.  After much faffing trying to extract the data out of this file, it did indeed contain various versions of my CV from that period so I'm back up & running.

(Apparently I don't have enough reputation to actually close my topic)

Comment: Have you ever emailed someone your CV? Do you know anyone at one of your old employers who could get one from your file?

Comment: Do you have a LinkedIn profile or other job-seeker's website profile?

Comment: If you have applied for a job online recently you should check out the website where you applied and see if you can log in and get a copy. I believe sites like Reed have this functionality.

Comment: I've not had to apply for a job in over 10 years, so there's nothing on any job search sites, I'm not on LinkedIn and I'm not in a position to ask previous employers.  I did manage to quietly ask an admin at my current place but they don't have it on file any more.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.gov.uk/get-proof-employment-history

Comment: Mathew, if you add that as an answer I'll mark it as correct, I think that's the best I'm going to get (and I'm feeling dumb for not thinking of that)

Comment: I suppose you've only got recent P60s/P45s as well?  I tend to keep start and end documentation indefinitely as it's more hassle clearing it out than keeping it.

Comment: Chris, all in the lost boxes.

I've looked further at the gov.uk option and it seems that is meant for compensation claims and won't go back as far as I'd need.  I have been able to see my year-on-year NI contributions but that doesn't help with individual employers.

Comment: Do you have tax records that you can request from the tax office? Or have you worked in different countries, where they might not have tax records?

Comment: Not sure if it's also the case in the UK, but I get annual pension overview statements from previous employers, _and_ a convenient government-provided summary of those.

Comment: Related to what Kaz already said, have you ever emailed your resume? If so, you could check your sent emails. You might find your resume attached to one of your emails sent to a potential employer.

Comment: This is why I update my LinkedIn and Facebook whenever I get a new job.  I've had to re-build my CV couple times and all the data was there between these two sites.

Comment: Have you considered asking your current or fairly recent employer for a copy? They probably have it on file.

Comment: Not an answer but I feel like if you can't remember what is on your CV then you are going into too much detail.

Comment: CV files are (no matter the file format) usually very small, in the order of a few KiloBytes. Therefore it is natural to save them directly into Dropbox or similar other cloud drives. Or, alternatively, to just include them in your routinely backed up files. The easiest solution is to simply restore from the cloud or from your latest backup.

Comment: What @Kaz said, plus that if you have emailed someone your CV it should reasonably also still be in your "Sent Mail" folder.

Comment: What industry do you work in? Some industries, e.g. software development,  are fine with a briefly summarized or project-based CV, max 2 pages, especially for older workers.

Comment: Glad you managed to sort it! Any particular reason you want the question closed? If it's been resolved to your satisfaction by one of the answers you should be able to mark that answer as "Accepted". If you just want it closing then I'm sure one of the mods can do it for you?

Answer (score 71):

In general potential employers are only going to really be interested in the last 10-15 years of relevant experience.

So start at "now" and work backwards, as WorkerWithoutACause says approximate month and the year is really all the precision you'll ever need in the timings, it would be very unusual for slight inaccuracies in this to even be noticed much less become an issue and it's perfectly normal to generalize more as you go further back and in fact this is generally considered to be the "right" thing to do in order to keep the CV optimized!

Comment: Very much this. A CV isn't a magical fact sheet that gives you the right to work in a position. It's a document that's intended to give a prospective employer an idea of who you are and what you've done, to entice them into inviting you in for a job interview. During the interview you can further make it clear what your strengths and weaknesses are and what value you can add to the prospective employer, while also getting a sense of the company and deciding if this is a company you *want* to be adding value to.

Comment: Whilst I agree generally with what you say, there are some gaps there are too big to be brushed over.

Comment: @jimbo-ish - gaps are not for you to worry about. Last 10 years, plus summary of "previous experience", grouped NOT by years/employers/positions, but functionally, looks better on CV anyway(and dates you less). **If** they ask (they might not care) about being redundant 20 years ago, answer the truth (think about it and prepare/rehears the answer) but don't bring it yourself. Such mishaps is part of having such long working experience. Good luck!

Comment: @PeterMasiar As someone in a hiring position, gaps *are* something for a potential employee to care about.  I (and my manager) want to know whether it was just unfortunate, or whether you've got a track record of working for about 2 years and then resigning to take the next year off to go travelling.  And if you were unemployed, we want to know you've spent that time doing something productive instead of just watching Jeremy Kyle in your jimjams.  We don't care about exact dates though, so don't stress too much over that.

Comment: @Graham - yes I agree with you that gaps are something for employer to worry about - but not for job applicant. mantra is: **do not volunteer in CV any info damaging to you:** let employer to ask for it (and have good answer prepared). Exactly like employer will not say in job description that position includes involuntary unpaid overtimes caused by marketing dept underbiding on a  contract, or struggling on a death march project caused by incompetent management promised unrealistic deadlines to a key customer. OP should not lie, but also should not raise red flags.

Comment: HR person here - with OP being from the UK, I would not underestimate this exercise. Our UK HR teams are routinely getting requests from agencies and prospective employers about people who worked **20 years ago or more** for a company that a company bought that another company bought, after which we acquired it ourselves. And not unfrequently we are getting angry calls from said ex-employees about why we are unable to confirm the employment for back then and that it may cost them their job offer.

Comment: @Eleshar Wow! Sounds like material for a new Q&A on workplace.SE. On the other hand, also in the UK, I have worked for several employers that are no longer in business (not my fault, I hope!). As far as I know, no-one ever tried to call them. Perhaps those agencies and employers have jobs requiring security clearance.

Comment: @QSigma That can be. Btw this is just anecdotal experience, I do not live or work in the UK, some of our teams just do HR for the UK part of our company. Now we are used to this but at the beginning we were seriously baffled.

Answer (score 25):

For the past twenty years (give or take), you may have email records of when you started and ended certain jobs. If all else fails, you could try looking at your bank records. Depending on your bank, they may retain records from further back in time. It could give you an idea of when you were working in various places. It may take some time to go through decades of records, but it will be as accurate as you could ask for.

Online applications that ask for exact dates can be frustrating, but for a CV, just the month and year will suffice 99% of the time.

Comment: Bank records was a good idea (and the kind of thing I was after when I asked the question),  unfortunately I've only got the last seven years available to me.

Comment: Ah then I think pension or government records might be worth looking at next. They'll probably be keeping track of where your income has been coming from for tax reasons.

Comment: I would try HMRC, they should have generally good overview who you were getting your salary from because they would be paying statutory deductions on your behalf.

Answer (score 10):

For CVs all that is needed is the month and year for start/end dates, e.g.

> Jan-15 to present, Chief Widget Maker at Widget Co.

For people with lot's of experience, you can summarise anything older than 10 years in one catch all statement (which you may want to include the years), e.g.

> 15 years' widget building experience (2000-2015)

Comment: In some industries more detail than your "15 years experience" is required -- many jobs in finance for example.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your country you can check social security systems.
When I log into their website, I see:

social security service:

- list of all insurance times (including start-/end-date and which company). this does not include positions, times of not-reported work like unpaid internships or education

pension insurance service:

- for each month I see which company paid how much into the pension insurance

taxes:

- list of employers per year and how much I was paid for the last 7 (?) years

The information you get from there is not complete and needs some reworking but at least it is a good starting point and help for memory. If you can't access the information directly it might be worth calling the corresponding institution and asking them.